# Confirm behavior when disconnect cast on android 11

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Currently, we implement chromecast on Android TV receiver. We have an issue bellow need you confirm: When use android 11 device cast to android TV receiver after that we disconnect cast on android 11 device then android TV receiver force to home (it is different with android under 11 devices. On android under 11 when disconnect on it then app on android TV receiver still playing). So we need confirm behavior when disconnect Cast on android device is force app to home or app still playing. Please help us confirm on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different Receiver API's 1. Web Receiver API 2. Android TV Receiver API. Web receiver api will tear down and takes you back to home page. If you have implemented ATV receiver then Android TV apps behave as Receiver apps which then continues to play even after you disconnect form the sender.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/atv_receiver/packages

Comment: Currently, i implement ATV receiver and when stop cast on android bellow 11 then ATV receiver continues play but when stop cast on android 11 then ATV receiver stop and go to home. Please help me check it. Thanks –